# How to empty input field after certain time delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have only one input field in py landing page. After enter the email id on success...

```
success: function(result){
  console.log(result.status);
  if(result.status == true) {
    $('input').attr("style", "color:green");
    $('input').delay(5000).val("");
  } else {
    $('input').attr("style", "color:red");
    $('input').delay(5000).val("");
  }
}
```

The problem is delay not working... is that my mistake or other way around it ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`delay` only works with animating methods. You can use the `setTimeout` function:

```
success: function(result){
    var color = result.status ? 'green' : 'red';
    var $input = $('input').css("color", color);
    setTimeout(function() { $input.val(''); }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 20 secs

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() { $input.val(''); }, 5000);
```